# HealthChecks Setup in Kubernetes

Tags: c#, .net, kubernetes-health-check, health-check

I've setup healthchecks for my app running in kubernetes.
https://github.com/Xabaril/AspNetCore.Diagnostics.HealthChecks/blob/master/doc/k8s-ui-discovery.md

I see the healthchecks working under /healthui endpoint:

[image]

Kubernetes service yaml:
[image]

I have HealthCheckUI defined in my ConfigMaps yaml:

[image]

However I get an exception:

[image]

How does one setup HealthChecksUI in kubernetes?

Comment: To me, that sounds like the instance doesn't have the required roles/permissions to access Kubernetes management APIs

Comment: Can you paste logs and service yaml file in proper format ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is about access forbidden. Not about Healtchecks, have a look at the service account you are using if it has enough permission for listing services.